# Set a single SMTC metadata for multiple MediaPlayers

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

In my UWP app I have multiple MediaPlayer that run simultaneously, but I want them to appear as one in the System Media Transport Controls. Is there a way to set a single SMTC metadata for all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to set a single SMTC metadata for all of them?

SMTC will automatically detect and display information for every instance of `MediaPlayer` that your app creates. If you want to use multiple instances of `MediaPlayer` but want the SMTC to provide a single entry for your app, then you must manually control the behavior of the SMTC instead of relying on automatic integration. Details please reference [Manual control of the SMTC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/integrate-with-systemmediatransportcontrols#manual-control-of-the-smtc).

For how to manually control the behavior please reference [Manual control of the System Media Transport Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/system-media-transport-controls) and the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/dev/Samples/SystemMediaTransportControls).

Special for set the SMTC metadata you mentioned above you could reference [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/system-media-transport-controls#update-the-system-media-transport-controls-with-media-info-and-thumbnails). You could show the metadata just as what you want.

Comment: When I try to update the metadata using this code:             `updater.MusicProperties.Artist = "artist";`
 I get this error \ `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
  HResult=0x80070032
  Message=The request is not supported.

The media type has not been initialized.  Please provide a valid media type first in order to access these properties.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>`

Comment: @samueledassatti Have set the `MediaPlaybackType` ? `await updater.CopyFromFileAsync(MediaPlaybackType.Music, currentMediaFile);` If you still have issues, could you please tell what the media format (for example, mp4 or mp3) you are playing? I will test it on my side later.

Comment: I'm currently using this code, how can I set the `MediaPlaybackType` in this: `SystemMediaTransportControlsDisplayUpdater updater = _systemMediaTransportControls.DisplayUpdater;
updater.MusicProperties.Artist = "artist";
updater.Update();

Comment: @samueledassatti, try this `updater.Type = MediaPlaybackType.Music;`